# ERROR: Unable to bind the runtime of the zero reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image-uploading, cloudinary

I literally follow this guide http://cloudinary.com/documentation/dotnet_image_upload#direct_uploading_from_the_browser to make a simple web-application for client-side uploading photos (I am using asp.net mvc).

Here is my view: http://pastebin.com/JGew5hcf ,

my controller http://pastebin.com/EjsfUGA3 ,

and my Photo.cs model http://pastebin.com/sad97QQe .

Guide doesn't say that I need to create any model for 'Photo' class at all, but I need to create it cause of 41st line in my controller.

And I have a strange error appearing when I am trying to run my app, it says "Unable to bind the runtime of the zero reference". It stops the caret on the 11th line of my View (that line is "@Model.Cloudinary.Api.BuildUploadForm... ").

Here is StackTrace: http://pastebin.com/uLpwZJUy .

Also, my project has CloudinaryDotNet nuget package installed.

**UPD:** manually specified 'cors_location' string, cause I think that it is a core of the problem. I've set this link to local path to the file but didn't succeed: `@{string cors_location = "http://localhost:50742/Content/cloudinary_cors.html";}`

the same mistake.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding following code to controller my app worked.

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    static Cloudinary m_cloudinary;

    static HomeController()
    {
        PhotoAlbumContainer album = new PhotoAlbumContainer();
        album.Database.Initialize(false);

        Account acc = new Account(
                "cloud name",
                "api_key",
                "api_secret_key");

        m_cloudinary = new Cloudinary(acc);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new DictionaryModel(m_cloudinary, new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "unsigned", "false" } });
        return PartialView("UploadDirectly", model);
    }...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check official cloudinary github repo for .net 
https://github.com/cloudinary/CloudinaryDotNet

and read the docs
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/dotnet_integration#getting_started_guide

Comment: So you don't know what exactly causes this problem?
I've read through this articles by clodinary, for me it seems that for client-side uploading I don't need do all this stuff.

Comment: in this repo You got 3 ways to upload :server side, client side , and unsigned  client side .... Hide Your APi KEY :)

Comment: Api key is not a very big secret, as it is about Secret_api_key. I just want to  make unsigned client side uploading. ok, going to try one more time.

Comment: rtfm is not helpful. he already pointed out that he's read the docs.